# $var[] and array_push() overwrites what mysqli_stmt_fetch() returned

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am fetching multiple rows from a DB via mysqli prepared statement. This is happening in a separate function, which should return me an array, whereas each key of the array will hold an assoc. array with the one DB row. Makes sense, right?

So I get to this point:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$row['employee_ID'],$row['name'],...);

$returnedarray = array();

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    $returnedarray[] = $row;
}
```

Expecting that I will take each row and push it into the returnedarray.

But once the array gets returned - and if there were 5 rows in the result set, it will hold the LAST row 5 times...

So I tried this:

```
$counter = 1;
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    echo '<br><b>GOING '. $counter++ .'</b><br>';

    echo '<br>ROW: ';
    print_r($row);
    echo '<br>';

    $returnedarray[] = $row;

    echo '<br>RETURNED ARRAY: ';
    print_r($returnedarray);
}
```

And what will be echoed looks somewhat like this:

> **GOING 1**
>
> ROW: Array ( [employee_ID] => 2 [name] => robert ... )
>
> RETURNED ARRAY: Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_ID] => 2 [name] =>
>   robert ... ) )
>
> **GOING 2**
>
> ROW: Array Array ( [employee_ID] => 3 [name] => john ... )
>
> RETURNED ARRAY: Array ( [0] => Array ( [employee_ID] => 3 [name] =>
>   john ... ) [1] => Array ( [employee_ID] => 3 [name] => john ... ) )

So even though $row holds exactly what I want each time, and I push it into the array as a NEW index, it actually overwrites ALL EXISTING indexes/indices with $row.

**Why doesn't it leave the existing indices alone??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comment on the [mysqli_stmt::fetch manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) addresses this:
"the problem is that the $row returned is reference and not data. So, when you write  $array[] = $row, the $array will be filled up with the last element of the dataset."
There's an alternate solution there too.

```
// loop through all result rows
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    foreach( $row as $key=>$value )
    {
        $row_tmb[ $key ] = $value;
    }
    $array[] = $row_tmb;

}
```

Comment: thanks buddy, this has been driving me nuts for the last hour and a half... -.-

Comment: I'm nut for past 4 hours too!